# Алгоритм перестановочного шифра

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте, возникли проблемы при написании программы перестановочного шифра на c#, в который надо изменить порядок слов. В качестве ключа выбирается перестановка чисел от 0 до n. По умолчанию я задал порядок 3,2,5,7,4,6,1, который соответствует исходному тексту. Этим куском кода я изменил порядок слов на 1,2,3,4,5,6,7. Порядок слов изменился правильно. Каждой букве соответствует одна цифра ключевого слова, если букв больше, то ключевое слово повторяется.
А в задании еще сказано: Расшифрование осуществляется тем же самым образом, но используется другой ключ. Чтобы получить ключ расшифрования нужно зашифровать строку "1234567"; при этом мы получим "7215364". 
А как получить именно такой порядок ключа: "7215364", а затем из него обратно 3,2,5,7,4,6,1, чтобы получить исходный код? Может кто сталкивался подскажите.

```
 private string get_abc(string key) // Сортировать буквы ключа по алфавиту
    {
        int i, j, x;
        string sw;
        for (j = 0; j < key.Length; j++)
            abc[j] = j;
        for (i = 0; i < key.Length - 1; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < key.Length - i - 1; j++)
                if (key[j] > key[j + 1])
                {
                    sw = key;
                    key = key.Remove(j, 2).Insert(j, sw.Substring(j + 1, 1)).Insert(j + 1, sw.Substring(j, 1));
                }

        return key;
    }
```

Comment: Исходному тексту может соответствовать только единичная перестановка, оставляющая всё на месте. 
Что значит Ваш ключ по умолчанию? Из Вашего вопроса непонятно, где надо изменить порядок слов: в программе или в перестановочном шифре? В программе обычно нельзя менять слова, а перестановочный шифр - это либо алгоритм, либо шифртекст. Менять слова в шифртексте затруднительно, поскольку там обычно просто байты и неясно, что такое слово, а перестановка приводит к суперпозиции с еще одним шифрованием. 
Если шифр перестановочный, то ключом расшифрования должна быть обратная перестановка

Answer (score 1):

гм. вопрос не совсем понятен. Но если Вам надо получить исходный ключ зная ключ расшифровки - просто зашифруйте ключем расшифровки последовательность 1234567... Как говорится все просто... ключ шифрования обратен ключю дешифрования и наоборот. Т.е. если Вы возьмете для шифрования ключ 7215364 то для дешифровки будете использовать ваш исходный 3,2,5,7,4,6,1...

Answer (score 0):

Прочитав вопрос, действительно, складывается впечатление, что автор не совсем понимает о чем спрашивает. 
Может вам стоит уточнить вопрос.
Или как минимум написать, что вы понимаете под словами "По умолчанию я задал порядок 3,2,5,7,4,6,1, который соответствует исходному тексту.". Предполагается, что если у вас была последовательность букв АБВГДЕЖ вы получите ВБДЖГЕА? (Я думаю вы это предполагаете под шифром)  Но дальше опять, "Каждой букве соответствует одна цифра ключевого слова, если букв больше, то ключевое слово повторяется.", что к чему? (Имеется в виду, что если в кодируемом слове больше 7 букв, то следующие опять кодируются тем же ключом?)

НУ допусти, что я правильно расшифровал начало вашего вопроса.
Те вы получили ключ 7,2,1,5,3,6,4. И теперь хотите зашифровать, уже зашифрованный текст так, что бы получилось, как будто вы его зашифровали один раз ключем 3,2,5,7,4,6,1.
Ести да, тогда вам нужно посмотреть как преобразовать 7215364 в 3257461. Для этого очевидно, нужно его еще раз зашифровать с ключем 5,2,4,1,7,6,3.

И у вас получится текст, расшифровать который можно так же, как будто его зашифровали порядком 3,2,5,7,4,6,1.

Думаю вы спрашивали именно это. (перечитал его раза 4)

Comment: гм....... глубокомысленно молчу.... (офф-топик, конечно, просто с трудом прослеживается нить кто, что, и чем зашифровал и что с этим чем-то надо сделать.... :)